# Is there a word meaning "well-intentioned but harmful"

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance, say someone is building a house.  Someone else makes a well-intentioned suggestion that would have been obviously bad to a person with experience building houses.  Ultimately, that suggestion results in disastrous consequences.

Or say that someone is sick, and someone with no medical training or experience suggests a recourse that leads to the person getting sicker, especially when it is known to the medical community that the recourse would be harmful.

Is there a word to describe that kind of ignorant advice from someone outside their knowledge/expertise?  Or to describe the person giving that kind of advice?

"Their friend's suggestion was ____" or "Their friend's ____ suggestion" or even "Their ____ friend's suggestion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it in your question - *ignorant advice*. I think [*uninformed*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/540899/388094) comes close but is rather just factual in tone, it doesn't quite cover the good intentions and the dire results.

One word that is often used to convey both these aspects, and the accompanying emotion, is

**ill-advised**

> "Their friend's **ill-advised** suggestion being followed led to dire consequences.

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ill-advised): 1. not wise, and likely to cause problems in the future: 2. unwise or not carefully considered.

Answer (score 2):

How about **uninformed**? From Lexico:

> **uninformed**: Not having or showing awareness or understanding of the facts.

If someone makes an **uninformed** suggestion, one may assume the suggestion is well-intentioned. After all, it *is* a suggestion. Also, by virtue of being uninformed, it's likely that the suggestion, if implemented, will lead to undesirable results, with how undesirable depending on the circumstances. After all, the suggestion does not reflect an understanding of the relevant facts.

Your examples:

> "Their friend's suggestion was **uninformed**" or "Their friend's **uninformed** suggestion" or even "Their **uninformed** friend's suggestion"

Answer (score 0):

A single word doesn't come to mind--but "the road to hell is paved with good intentions" tends to get the point across.

Comment: But the single word was what was requested quite clearly.